# In C, how do I print the index of however many values the user chooses to input?

Tags: arrays, c

I am essentially attempting to print out how many values are entered for the array in this code (If they enter 10 numbers, I would want to print for index: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 as well as taking user inputs for the array values and printing those in a table-like fashion beside of their index). How would I go about doing this, and is there anything wrong with this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int arr_1 (int ar[], int size);

int main()
{
    double sentinel[20];

    printf("Hello User!\n\nEnter up to 20 values, and type -1 when you are finished: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        scanf("%lf", &sentinel[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        printf("%f\n", sentinel[i]);
    }

    printf("\n%lu\n", sizeof(sentinel[20]));
}

int arr_1 (int ar[], int size)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Side note: It does not make sense to give an array the name `sentinel`. The sentinel value is the value at the end of the array.

Comment: I should specify that they want us to prompt the user to enter -1 to signal the end of the array. I am not sure how to go about this

Comment: Please [edit] the question if you want to add additional information. Don't use the comments section for that. You should only use the comments section for replying to comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you will need to check whether the user actually inputs as many values as you expect to get (20 in your case). The [`scanf()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm) function tells you, in its return value, whether it actually managed to parse another number from the input.

Then, you'll need to exit your loop when no more numbers are available on the input.

Finally, you'll need to keep track of how far you got in the loop. One way to do this is to define the loop index (`i`) in the scope *outside* the loop. That way it's not lost to you when the loop is eventually cleared.

Once you have the last `i` value (suppose you assign it to a new variable like so, `int num_input_elements = i + 1`) then you know your indices are `0`, `1`,... `num_input_elements - 1`. And you can easily loop through those, printing, in fact, your loop index.

Additional notes:

- Don't use the "magic number" 20 all over. Use a preprocessor definition before you first use it, e.g. something like `#define MAX_NUM_ELEMENTS 20`.
- `sentinel` is a confusing name for your array, because a sentinel typically means [something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) in programming.
- `sizeof(sentinel[20])` is always `sizeof(double)`... *not* the number of elements you got on the input.

Comment: In your answer, you wrote: `"sizeof(sentinel[20]) is always exactly 20 times sizeof(int)"` -- This statement is incorrect. The expression `sizeof(sentinel[20])` is equivalent to `sizeof(*sentinel)`, which is equivalent to `sizeof(double)`. Actually, it may be undefined behavior, because `sentinel[20]` does not actually exist, due to accessing the array out of bounds. I'm not sure if that rule also applies inside of a `sizeof` expression.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help and the additional notes; I really appreciate it! 

I'll go ahead and implement these into my code, and again I do appreciate the help.

Comment: @neelish: You are welcome, but here on StackOverflow the way to acknowledge an answer which resolves your question/problem is to _accept_ it by clicking the checkmark to its side, and possibly _upvoting_ it by clicking the up-arrow.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Andreas; could I instead say sizeof(double) then?

Comment: @einpoklum apolgoies, it would not let me upvote the answer but I was able to click the checkmark!

Comment: @neelish: Yes, you cannot upvote the answer yet. I believe you need 15 reputation points for that. So don't worry about that, you did nothing wrong.

Comment: @einpoklum: I believe OP intended to write `sizeof(sentinel)` instead of `sizeof(sentinel[20])`, so the explanation in your answer is still good (except for confusing `sizeof(int)` with `sizeof(double)`) and should not be removed. Therefore, I suggest that you instead point out that additional mistake.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel: Yes, that was a gaffe on my part, fixed.